# How to pass parameters in HTML form to text box if value contains double quotes

Tags: html, forms, post, escaping, quotes

As an integration test to a web service that reads in http POST body as graphQL, I want to be able to run an HTML file that contains a graphQL string in a parameter value.  HTML file contents:

```
<form method="POST" action="https://localhost/graphql/authenticate">
    <input type="text" name="auth" value="{"Query":"query getToken($clientToken: String!, $password: String!)","OperationName":"getToken","Variables":{"clientToken":"appToken","password":"myPassword"}}" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

But if I run this, the html form shown only contains {
in the text box.  I've tried to replace the double quotes in the value = "" field with ", with &quot, with ', with %22, but none of these let me read the whole string:

```
{"Query":"query getToken($clientToken: String!, $password: String!)","OperationName":"getToken","Variables":{"clientToken":"appToken","password":"myPassword"}}
```

in the text box.

Comment: Can you not simply encase the entire string within single quotes rather than the double quotes?

Comment: This works!  thanks, if you post as answer, I'll accept it